# Clustering points in Lizmap?

Tags: qgis, clustering, qgis-server, lizmap

I am testing Lizmap on a project where I display a high density of points from a point layer.

Anyone knows a way to cluster the points in lizmap or qgis server?

The idea is to end up with some clusters similar to this:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-markercluster/
http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/attachment/ticket/3700/cluster.png

Comment: Are you using WMS or WFS like in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lizmap is based on OpenLayers 2 so if you want to cluster points from a WFS, you'll have to use [OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html)

You can [extend lizmap with javascript](http://docs.3liz.com/fr/publish/advanced_lizmap_config.html#adding-your-own-javascript) and change the way your WFS layer is displayed. Take a look at this [example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html) to understand how to use clustering with OpenLayers 2.

Answer (score 0):

With the [QGIS-WPS4server](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-wps4server) , you can use scripts, models, etc that create cluster from QGIS Desktop on QGIS server.
So after that i suppose you have to link this to a button in the lizmap client or something else.